# Applescript can't get process "..."

Tags: macos, applescript

I am getting an error in applescript

In the first script i created a search engine and the script is as follows

```
on dialogBox(theMessage)
display dialog theMessage default answer "" buttons {"Cancel", "Search"} default button 2 with title "Pick a search engine"
end dialogBox


set search to text returned of dialogBox("Enter Google Search")
tell application "Safari"
activate
open location "https://www.google.com/?    gfe_rd=cr&ei=4fJgVJ6SM8yD8QfJjYGICA&gws_rd=ssl,cr&fg=1#q=" & search
end tell
```

and i exported that script as an application called google

In the second script the code is as follows:

```
tell application "System Events"
tell process "google"
    click button "Search" of window "Pick a Search engine"
end tell
end tell
```

however when i try to run the code i get the following error:

System Events got an error: Can’t get process "google".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A running script won't actually have the process name 'google' even if that's what you called the script; it will be called 'applet'

To get the OS to recognise it as a distinct process you need to edit the applet's resource structure…

From http://macscripter.net/viewtopic.php?id=25707

> If you change the .plist executable name of your app, you must change the name of the executable file to match, as well as the name of the 'applet.rsrc' file.
>
> CFBundleExecutable - scraper
>   executable name - scraper
>   applet.rsrc - scraper.rsrc
>
> If you change the .plist creator type of your app, you must change the 'PkgInfo' file contents to match.
>
> CFBundleSignature - scrp
>   PkgInfo - APPLscrp
>
> You may also need to Zip the original app, toss the original, then open the archived app to get changes to 'stick'.